# How to simplify a query between Many to Many Relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering how to simplify this query, here(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2789c/4) you have the complete example

```
SELECT distinct (R.[roleId])
FROM [Role] R
LEFT  JOIN [userRole] U ON R.[roleId] = U.[roleId]
WHERE R.RoleID NOT IN(
  SELECT [roleId] 
  from [dbo].[userRole] 
  WHERE userId = 2)
```

I want to get all the roles that are not assigned to an specific user. I think the inner select could be erase.

**Update 1**

After your great help, I could use only one `SELECT` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2789c/87

```
SELECT R.[roleID]
FROM [Role] R
LEFT  JOIN [userRole] U
ON R.[roleID] = U.[roleID] AND U.userId = @userID
WHERE U.userId IS NULL
```

Comment: You need the query to be simplified? Is the current result correct?

Comment: What I want is to see if this query could be simplified. The current result is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As simple as it gets:

```
select roleId
  from Role
except
select roleId
  from userRole
 where userId = 2
```

Comment: Certainly seems the simplest, but is it efficient to use `except` in this case?

Comment: As efficient as using join (join type in my case was Nested Loops, with no indexes etc.) - so it's pretty much optimal.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT R.roleId
FROM [Role] R
LEFT JOIN [userRole] U ON R.roleId = U.roleId
group by r.roleId
having sum(case when U.userId = 2 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2789c/20)

Comment: Could you please give a short explanation of `having sum(case when U.userId = 2 then 1 else 0 end) = 0`?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this

```
Select distinct role.roleID from role , userrole
except 
select roleId from userrole where userID=2
```

OR

```
SELECT R.roleId
FROM [Role] R
LEFT JOIN [userRole] U ON R.roleId = U.roleId
except 
select roleId from userrole where userID=2
```